# gitignore not working - want to ignore everything but gitignore file to keep an 'empty' directory

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a `.gitignore` file in a few directories (ex. `log/`) with the following contents:

```
*            " Ignore everything in this directory
!.gitignore  " Except this file
```

Nonetheless, if there is a file in that directory, `git status` shows it to me saying it's new but untracked.

```
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       log/blah.log
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

I have found other posts on stackoverflow suggesting putting a comment on the first line and various other forms or random voodoo, but nothing has worked.

Simply, I want a `tmp/` and `log/` directory to exist in my repo, but empty. I don't want anyone to be harassed to add their log and tmp files to these directories.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you expecting the double-quote to act like a comment in your
`.gitignore` file?  You've got this...

```
*            " Ignore everything in this directory
!.gitignore  " Except this file
```

...but that's doing what you want.  If you replace it with simply:

```
*
!.gitignore
```

It will work just fine.  Watch:

```
$ ls -A
dir1 .git
$ ls -A dir1
.gitignore
$ cat dir1/.gitignore
*
!.gitignore
$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
$ touch dir1/file{1,2,3}
$ ls -A dir1
file1 file2 file3 .gitignore
$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Comment: You should note that a line starting with `#` serves as a comment in the `.gitignore` file.